# Creating a google plus / digg like social bookmark button

Tags: php, javascript

For a client of ours we need to create a share button for his site so that the users of his site can add this button to their blogs / sites and others can click on it and it will just open up a popup asking the user to login (if already logged in, the link bookmark page appears) to the clients site and bookmark it. Can somebody guide me on how to do it with php and javascript?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make a button like 'Digg it' for my website?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/410820/how-can-i-make-a-button-like-digg-it-for-my-website)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to implement this yourself why not try a 3rd party plugin like http://www.sharethis.com/ ?

It does all of the leg work for you and is very flexible.

Comment: I cant use that functionality, because the client is looking for a site like digg.

Comment: right well its not a valid question, it would depend entirely on how you've built your database and user system!